# Tiling rectangles with N pentomino plus rectangles

Tags: geometry, computer-puzzle, tiling, polyomino

Inspired by [Polyomino Z pentomino and rectangle packing into rectangle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9403/polyomino-z-pentomino-and-rectangle-packing-into-rectangle)

Also in this series:
[Tiling rectangles with F pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64146/tiling-rectangles-with-f-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

[Tiling rectangles with T pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64148/tiling-rectangles-with-t-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

[Tiling rectangles with U pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64149/tiling-rectangles-with-u-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

[Tiling rectangles with V pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64151/tiling-rectangles-with-v-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

[Tiling rectangles with W pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64011/tiling-rectangles-with-w-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

[Tiling rectangles with X pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64152/tiling-rectangles-with-x-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

The goal is to tile rectangles as small as possible with the N pentomino. Of course this is impossible, so we allow the addition of copies of a rectangle. For each rectangle $a\times b$, find the smallest area larger rectangle that copies of $a\times b$ plus at least one N-pentomino will tile. Example shown, with the $1\times 1$, you can tile a $2\times 4$ as follows:

[image: F plus 1x1]

Now we don't need to consider $1\times 1$ any longer as we have found the smallest rectangle tilable with copies of N plus copies of $1\times 1$.

There are at least 22 more solutions. More expected. I tagged it 'computer-puzzle' but you can certainly work some of these out by hand. The larger ones might be a bit challenging.

Comment: My program found another tiling for this one. So now there are thirteen left to find. Should I put hints on these as to the rectangles which have tilings?

Comment: This is identical to mine challenges, however, let it be. I decided not to post them, because they do not have so much solutions or have infinitely many. This one has infinitely many.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my (now improved) solution for $2\times3$ rectangles plus N-pentomino(s):

> It is a $7\times8$ rectangle, using four N-pentominoes and six $2\times3$ rectangles.
>
>  [image]

And here is my solution for $2\times5$ rectangles plus N-pentomino(s):

> It is a $7\times10$ rectangle, using two N-pentominoes and six $2\times5$ rectangles.
>
>  [image]

Here are some more solutions, though for these I used computer assistance.

$1\times6$ rectangles plus N-pentomino(s):

> It is an $8\times13$ rectangle, using 16 N-pentominoes and four $1\times6$ rectangles.
>
>  [image]

The solutions given by others for $1\times3$ and $1\times5$ generalise to give solutions for $1\times(5k+3)$ rectangles and $1\times 5k$ rectangles.

> A $(5k+4)\times(10k+5)$ rectangle can be filled with $2k+1$ N-pentominoes and $10k+5$ rectangles of size $1\times(5k+3)$.
>  Similarly, a $(5k+1)\times 10k$ rectangle can be filled with $2k$ N-pentominoes and $10k$ rectangles of size $1\times 5k$.
>
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

Here is a solution for the $1\times7$ rectangle plus N-pentomino(s), which also generalises in the same way to $1\times(5k+2)$ :

> It is an $(5k+3)\times(10k+5)$ rectangle, using $2k+1$ N-pentominoes and $10k+5$ rectangles of size $1\times(5k+2)$ .
>
>  [image]

There is also a family of solutions for $2\times(10k+7)$ rectangles.

> A $(20k+16)\times(20k+15)$ rectangle can be filled with $8k+6$ N-pentominoes and $20k+15$ rectangles of size $2\times(10k+7)$.
>
>  [image]
>  [image]

Comment: The 2x5 is minimal, but the 2x3 is not. So 12 left to find.

Comment: @theonetruepath I have now improved the $2\times3$ solution.

Comment: 2x3 now minimal, as is the 1x6. There is a smaller 1x7. Your 1x3 generalisation to 1x8 (9x15) is minimal too. In fact a very similar design will give you the minimal 1x7 tiling. I'll do a summary at some point.

Comment: Your 2x7 is not minimal either, although it's not far off.

Comment: 1x(5k+2) and 2x(10k+5) should be easily generalizable as well.

Comment: I have now improved and generalised the 1x7 solution to 1x(5k+2).

Comment: The 1x7 is now minimal.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an attempt for 1x4:

> 11x5 = 55 squares
>
>  [image]

and another one for 1x5:

> 10x6 = 60 squares
>
>  [image]

and one for 1x9:

> 14x14 = 196
>
>  [image]

and one for 1x10, smaller than the generalized 1x5k solution:

> 12x15 = 180
>
>  [image]

and one for 1x11; it looks like this sequence is somehow generalizable as well. N has a nice shape, it seems.

> 13x18 = 234
>
>  [image]

1x12:

> 18x16 = 288
>
>  [image]

Here is the minimal solution for $2 \times 7$, which generalizes to $2 \times (10k + 7)$ and is just a little bit smaller than the one discovered by Jaap:

> 15x15 = 255 (generalized: $(20k + 15) \times (20k + 15)$)
>  [image]

Comment: Both optimal. My tiling for the 1x4 is slightly different (still a 5x11). Most of these tilings are unique.

Comment: 1x9 and 1x10 both optimal. 1x11 probably optimal... I will have to run my program on that to check, I went only to 10x10

Comment: 13x18 for the 1x11 is optimal too.

Comment: 16x18 for the 1x12 also minimal

Answer (score 4):

**2x2**

This is smallest rectangle with N pentomino and O tetromino.

> $8 \times 20$: 
>
>  [image: 2x2]

**2x4**

This is smallest rectangle with N pentomino and 2x4 rectangle:

> $16 \times 16$: 
>
>  [image: 2x4]

**3x4**

This is smallest rectangle with N pentomino and 3x4 rectangle:

> $14 \times 16$: 
>
>  [image: 3x4]

**3x5**

> $16 \times 30$: 
>
>  [image: 3x5]

In general, there exists solution for each $2 \times n$ rectangle (note that these also give implicit solutions for all $1 \times n$ rectangles):

> Generalized solution for $2 \times n$ for odd $n$:
>
>  Resulting rectangle will be $2n \times (2 + lcm(5, n))$
>
>  [image: 2x9]
>
>  Generalized solution for $2 \times n$ for even $n$: 
>
>  Resulting rectangle will be $(4 + n + kn) \times (2 + n + 2mn)$ where $k \equiv 2n^{-1} \pmod{5}$ and $m \equiv 3n^{-1} \pmod{5}$
>
>  This one also solves for odd $n$ because you can join two rectangles to get even length, so for now this is most general solution.
>
>  [image: 2x6]

General solution for any rectangle with coprime sides $a \times b, a>1,b>1$:

> Resulting rectangle will be $(an + bm) \times (an + bm - 1 + lcm(5, a, b))$ where $n \equiv a^{-1}\pmod{b}$ and $m \equiv b^{-1}\pmod{a}$
>
>
>  This gives $16 \times 30$ solution for $3 \times 5$, $22 \times 126$ solution for $3 \times 7$ and $21 \times 40$ solution for $3 \times 4$
>
>  [image: axb]

Comment: Those general solutions are really great.

Comment: 2x2, 2x4, 3x4 all minimal. Minimality of the generalisations unclear... until my program gets a bit further

Comment: @theonetruepath Added 3x5, cannot check for minimality for now. Also added very general solution.

Comment: Your 3x5 is probably minimal, my program is up to area 456 now and a few more rectangles to check before I can confirm it. Progress is slow at these sizes... I like the general solution for axb with a,b co-prime.

Answer (score 3):

Let's give it a try:

$ 1 \times 2 $

> Area: $2 \times 7 = 14$
>  [image]

$ 1 \times 3 $

> Area: $4 \times 5 = 20$
>  [image]

Comment: Yup both are minimal. Nice colours! Only 14 to go...

Answer (score 2):

A 4 x 4 area can be tiled by two N pentominos and three 1 x 2 rectangles.

> `1 1 n n` 
>     `n n n 2` 
>     `N N N 2` 
>     `3 3 N N`

A 5 x 5 area can be tiled by two N pentominos and five 1 x 3 rectangles.

> `1 1 1 n n` 
>     `2 n n n 5` 
>     `2 3 3 3 5` 
>     `2 N N N 5` 
>     `4 4 4 N N`

Comment: [Add spoiler tags please.] Neither of these is optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Since the solutions are so widely spread across the answers, here's an attempt to put them
all together in a Community Wiki answer. If somebody has a better way of formatting this
inside a spoiler, be my guest.

#### $1 \times n$

> `1 x n       solution           found by, image`
>  `1 x 1          2 x  4 =   8    .`[theonetruepath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiV2I.gif)
>  `1 x 2          2 x  7 =  14    .`[athin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puoCU.png)
>  `1 x 3          4 x  5 =  20    .`[athin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trHzv.png)
>  `1 x 4          5 x 11 =  55    .`[Glorfindel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYAtC.png)
>  `1 x 5          6 x 10 =  60    .`[Glorfindel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUFX2.png)
>  `1 x 6          8 x 13 = 104    .`[Jaap Scherphuis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNq91.png)
>  `1 x 7          8 x 15 = 120    .`[Jaap Scherphuis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxYLr.png)
>  `1 x 9         14 x 14 = 196    .`[Glorfindel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdKUC.png)
>  `1 x 10        12 x 15 = 180    .`[Glorfindel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HrBn.png)
>  `1 x 11        13 x 18 = 234    .`[Glorfindel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhKvB.png)
>  `1 x 12        16 x 18 = 288    .`[Glorfindel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks7cX.png)
>  `1 x 5k      5k+1 x 10k         .`[Jaap Scherphuis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/up3qA.png)
>  `1 x 5k+2    5k+3 x 10k+5       .`[Jaap Scherphuis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxYLr.png)
>  `1 x 5k+3    5k+4 x 10k+5       .`[Jaap Scherphuis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Oysb.png)

#### $2 \times n$

> `2 x n       solution           found by, image`
>  `2 x 2          8 x 20 = 160    .`[Somnium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qplJ8.png)
>  `2 x 3          7 x  8 =  56    .`[Jaap Scherphuis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOCbi.png)
>  `2 x 4         16 x 16 = 256    .`[Somnium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW1LA.png)
>  `2 x 5          7 x 10 =  70    .`[Jaap Scherphuis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwk6o.png)
>  `2 x 7         15 x 15 = 225    .`[Glorfindel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ3Ih.png)
>  `2 x 2k       see below (*)     .`[Somnium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKMfS.png)
>  `2 x 2k+1    4k+2 x 2+lcm(5,2k) .`[Somnium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXqMh.png)
>  `2 x 10k+7 20k+15 x 20k+15      .`[Glorfindel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ3Ih.png)
>
>  `(*)`: solution size for $2 \times 2k$ is $(4 + 2k + 2lk) \times (2 + 2k + 4mk)$
>  where $l \equiv 4k^{-1} \pmod{5}$ and $m \equiv 6k^{-1} \pmod{5}$.

#### $3 \times n$ and others

> `3 x n       solution           found by, image`
>  `3 x 4         14 x 16 = 224    .`[Somnium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HjWT.png)
>  `3 x 5         16 x 30 = 480    .`[Somnium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhcso.png)
>  `a x b (*)    see below (*)     .`[Somnium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC9rc.png)
>
>  `(*)`: $a$ and $b$ must be coprime and greater than 1. The solution size is
>  $(an + bm) \times (an + bm - 1 + lcm(5, a, b))$
>  where $n \equiv a^{-1}\pmod{b}$ and $m \equiv b^{-1}\pmod{a}$.

Comment: The 1x8 is missing, but the smallest solution is the generalized one for 1x5k+3 found by Jaap Scherphuis.

Comment: (I know the alignment doesn't work on mobile; please view this answer in full site mode.)