# Tiling rectangles with T pentomino plus rectangles

Tags: geometry, computer-puzzle, tiling, polyomino

Inspired by [Polyomino Z pentomino and rectangle packing into rectangle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9403/polyomino-z-pentomino-and-rectangle-packing-into-rectangle)

Also in this series:
[Tiling rectangles with F pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64146/tiling-rectangles-with-f-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

[Tiling rectangles with N pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64147/tiling-rectangles-with-n-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

[Tiling rectangles with U pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64149/tiling-rectangles-with-u-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

[Tiling rectangles with V pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64151/tiling-rectangles-with-v-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

[Tiling rectangles with W pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64011/tiling-rectangles-with-w-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

[Tiling rectangles with X pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64152/tiling-rectangles-with-x-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

The goal is to tile rectangles as small as possible with the T pentomino. Of course this is impossible, so we allow the addition of copies of a rectangle. For each rectangle $a\times b$, find the smallest area larger rectangle that copies of $a\times b$ plus at least one T-pentomino will tile. Examples shown, with the $1\times 1$ or the $1\times 2$, you can tile a $3\times 3$ as follows:

[image: T plus 1x1 and 1x2]

Now we don't need to consider $1\times 1$ or $1\times 2$ any longer as we have found the smallest rectangle tilable with copies of T plus copies of $1\times 1$ and $1\times 2$.

There are at least 10 more solutions. I tagged it 'computer-puzzle' but you can certainly work some of these out by hand. The larger ones might be a bit challenging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume these are the remaining ones you found as well; for 2x3

> a simple 7x5 = 35 one:
>
>  [image]

for 2x2

> a 10x8 = 80 one
>
>  [image]

for 1x5:

> 11x10 = 110
>
>  [image]

for 2x4:

> 14x22 = 308
>
>  [image]

for 2x5:

> 12x15 = 180
>
>  [image]

for 3x4:

> 18x19 = 342
>
>  [image]

and finally a large one for 3x5

> which uses the same central figure formed by the Ts as the 1x5.
>  28x40 = 1120
>
>  [image]

Comment: Nice. Will have to wait for confirmation of minimality until I get back to Australia as my net connection there seems to be down.

Comment: I got a friend to power cycle my router, back online now. 2x3 into 5x7 is minimal. So are 2x2 into 8x10 and 1x5 into 10x11.

Comment: @theonetruepath I think I found the remaining ones, and I suspect there are none left. Forming long straight boundaries with just Ts is hard.

Comment: Yup all minimal except I can't confirm the 3x5 as my program hasn't got there yet. When I re-ran it after reconfiguring to avoid the bug which made me miss solutions occasionally, it found the 12x15 but I forgot to remove the 16x15 for the 2x5 which it had previously found instead. I think it's time to award the answer on this one...

Comment: @theonetruepath thanks. If there are 10 more solutions (other than 1x1 and 1x2) and your program hasn't found the 3x5 yet, we're still missing one as Riley found 3 and I found 7.

Comment: I thought there were 10 more but it turns out there were 10 more. I counted one extra and didn’t know about yours

Answer (score 4):

Here's three of them

> $3\times 6$ tiled with $1\times 4$

.

> [image]

.

> $4\times 4$ tiled with $1\times 3$

.

> [image]

.

> $8\times 8$ tiled with $1\times 6$. Not sure if optimal.

.

> [image]

Comment: All optimal yes