# Tiling rectangles with V pentomino plus rectangles

Tags: geometry, computer-puzzle, tiling, polyomino

Inspired by [Polyomino Z pentomino and rectangle packing into rectangle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9403/polyomino-z-pentomino-and-rectangle-packing-into-rectangle)

Also in this series:
[Tiling rectangles with F pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64146/tiling-rectangles-with-f-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

[Tiling rectangles with N pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64147/tiling-rectangles-with-n-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

[Tiling rectangles with T pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64148/tiling-rectangles-with-t-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

[Tiling rectangles with U pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64149/tiling-rectangles-with-u-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

[Tiling rectangles with W pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64011/tiling-rectangles-with-w-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

[Tiling rectangles with X pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64152/tiling-rectangles-with-x-pentomino-plus-rectangles)

The goal is to tile rectangles as small as possible with the V pentomino. Of course this is impossible, so we allow the addition of copies of a rectangle. For each rectangle $a\times b$, find the smallest area larger rectangle that copies of $a\times b$ plus at least one V-pentomino will tile. Examples shown, with the $1\times 1$, $1\times 2$ or $2\times 2$, you can tile a $3\times 3$ as follows:

[image: V plus 1x1, 1x2, 1x3]

Now we don't need to consider $1\times 1$, $1\times 2$, or $2\times 2$ any longer as we have found the smallest rectangle tilable with copies of V plus copies of each of those three.

There are at least 20 more solutions. I tagged it 'computer-puzzle' but you can certainly work some of these out by hand. The larger ones might be a bit challenging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are (most of) the remaining ones. An easy one for 1x5:

> [image]

and a more difficult one for 1x6:

> [image]

1x7 takes a lot more:

> 24x11 = 264
>
>  [image]

1x8:

> 16x11 = 176
>
>  [image]

1x9:

> 22x12 = 264
>
>  [image]

1x10:

> 13x30 = 390
>
>  [image]

1x12:

> 14x42 = 588
>
>  [image]

2x3:

> 4x8 = 32
>
>  [image]

2x5:

> 5x6 = 30
>
>  [image]

2x6:

> 8x12 = 96
>
>  [image]

2x7:

> 16x19 = 304
>
>  [image]

2x8:

> 17x18 = 306
>
>  [image]

2x9:

> 21x24 = 504
>
>  [image]

3x4:

> 7x18 = 126
>
>  [image]

3x5:

> 11x35 = 385
>
>  [image]

3x7:

> 13x48 = 624
>
>  [image]

3x8:

> 33x38 = 1254
>
>  [image]

4x5:

> 21x40 = 840
>
>  [image]

4x6:

> 26x36 = 936
>
>  [image]

5x6:

> 38x60 = 2280
>
>  [image]

I assume the number of solutions here is infinite (probably in both directions), I'll post more when I have them.

Comment: The 1x5 into 5x6 is minimal, your 1x6 into 6x10 is nice, but there's a smaller one

Comment: @theonetruepath ah, of course. I think I found it.

Comment: Yup that's minimal

Comment: 1x5, 1x6, 1x7, 1x8, 1x9 all minimal. At least 11 more to find.

Comment: I think I got (almost) all of them now.

Comment: All confirmed minimal except the three I haven't reached yet, ie 4x6, 4x5, 2x9. Time to award this one... although if they do go on forever someone could eventually overtake your total area tiled. Some of them are just weird, eg the 4x5

Answer (score 3):

20's a lot, but here's a few to get it started.

> $3\times 6$ tiled with a $2\times 4$

.

> [image]

.

> $3\times 6$ tiled with a $1\times 4$

.

> [image]

.

> $4\times 4$ tiled with a $1\times 3$

.

> [image]

.

> $6\times 6$ tiled with a $4\times 4$

.

> [image]

Comment: Yup all four are optimal