# Tiling a rectangle with just the Y pentomino

Tags: geometry, no-computers, tiling, polyomino

Inspired by [this question series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A43113+is%3Aq+%22pentomino+plus+rectangles%22), which was inspired by [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9403/polyomino-z-pentomino-and-rectangle-packing-into-rectangle). They give rise to beautiful pictures (at least in the eye of the <s>beholder</s> mathematician) and some nice generalizable solutions.

Together, they make eight questions of the type 'take a pentomino and some rectangle-shaped tiles, and try to fit them in a (bigger) rectangular box'. There are twelve pentominos; so four of them are left, and it's easy to see that it doesn't really make sense to ask the question for I, L and P because they trivially tile a 1x5 or 2x5 rectangle:

[image]
[image]

---

[image]

It turns out that the Y pentomino (see above) *also* tiles a rectangle without help of other rectangles, but the solution is a bit trickier and a nice puzzle, certainly doable by hand (that's where the [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) tag is for). So the actual puzzle here is:

> What is the smallest rectangle which can be tiled by Y pentominos?

Rotations and reflections of the pentomino are allowed, so you actually have 8 forms to work with.

One observation/hint (which, as expected, wasn't necessary, but might help future readers who want to solve this puzzle by themselves):

> The total area of the rectangle must be divisible by 5. Therefore, at least one of the sides must be divisible by 5 as well.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with the terminology, it would be helpful to have an image of a Y-pentomino, so we know what we're working with...

Comment: Why it is called as a *Y* pentomino...instead of any other letter pentomino..(for example _L_)?

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP35M.png

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I brute-forced a solution that I think is the smallest possible. I stumbled upon it while trying to fill a bigger rectangle:

> 5 x 10
>
>  [image]

Comment: Dang, beat me to it. I have a nice image I can edit in though.

Comment: Can you show that it's the smallest?

Comment: @noedne The only smaller configurations there are, given the shape of the pentomino, are 4×9, 5×9, and 4×10. As far as I can tell from spending a minute with pencil and paper those are all impossible. (That's about enough rigor for a comment, I think.)

Comment: @sebastian_k $4\times9$ is impossible, not being divisible by $5$. How did you arrive at these candidate configurations?

Comment: Oh man, I didn't even think that far. I was only thinking about the length of the edges. Yeah, that eliminates 4×9 right off the bat!

Comment: @noedne 4×N rectangles can't be filled given the shape of the pentomino. You'll always end up with 1×1/1×2 holes or a row of 4 without holes for the extra bit of the pentomino. Possible smaller configurations can only be 5×N.

Answer (score 7):

As @TwoBitOperation, I used paint to represent a possible answer:

> I found a 10*5 solution
>
>  [image]

Comment: Oh, too late :(

Answer (score 4):

I brute-forced an answer by hand in MS-Paint.  Figured I'd share.  The smallest I can get it is

> 15 x 10.

I do not know if a smaller answer exists

> [image: More like Y-did-I-spend-so-long-on-this pentominoes]

Comment: Nice! There is a smaller solution, though.

Comment: I'll keep at it then!  Thanks for the spoiler edit