# Tiling a rectangle with an odd number of Y pentomoes

Tags: geometry, no-computers, tiling, polyomino

Follow-on from [Tiling a rectangle with just the Y pentomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66114/tiling-a-rectangle-with-just-the-y-pentomino)

Two questions:

- Find the smallest rectangle that can be tiled with an odd number of
  Y pentominoes, or prove it impossible
- Find the smallest rectangle that can be tiled with an odd number of just
  'right-handed' Y pentominoes, i.e. no 'flipping', or prove it impossible

Here is a 5x10 tiled with right-handed Y pentominoes, by way of illustration. All that prevents it from being a valid answer to both questions, is the fact that there is an even number of them.

[image: Y5_10_noflip]

Comment: Need the solutions be proven smallest? This sounds difficult with [tag:no-computers].

Comment: @noedne smallest proof not required, smallest will probably be easiest anyway...

Comment: One observation for the 2nd question: *both* sides of the rectangle must be odd (obviously) but also divisible by 5 (otherwise, gaps will emerge close to the border).

Comment: I've stopped searching for a solution to part 2. In fact I believe I have a fairly simple parity/square-numbering impossibility proof if anyone wants to have a go at getting that. I'll post it in a day or two.

Comment: ...It still eludes me... not as close as I thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not really an answer [technically it is] ... but the answer to Q1 can be found [here](http://www.cflmath.com/Polyomino/Images/y5_15x15.gif):

> [image: 15x15 solution]

Comment: Does finding the answer online count as using [tag:no-computers]?

Comment: do i have remove  this answer ?

Comment: I don't know why you say this is "not really an answer". It looks like a valid answer to me, albeit a partial one.

Comment: @Q̞ī̯X̶͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇̯̯̳̳͈͈͈͆͆ No, I really don't know whether it does, and was hoping someone else could answer.

Comment: Not really an answer mainly because it uses both right- and left-handed Y pentominoes, as is easily seen by examining the three Ys with a long side on the top... they go right, left, right

Comment: Actually  i wrote "not really an answer" because the answer not originally  solve by me ,but now it make me confiuse what the questions  really are.

Comment: I was confussed... this is an answer to the first question, my bad.

Comment: I think this is a valid answer. [no-computers] is meant to discourage programming to solve the question (see also the [tag wiki](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/no-computers/info)). This answer would be equally valid if you looked it up in a book.

Comment: BTW, my computer search confirmed this to be the optimal solution to the first part of the question.

Comment: The second part is quite a bit trickier...

Comment: I know. I suspect it's impossible but I lack the time to prove it mathematically.