# Tiling rectangles with Hexomino plus rectangle #1

Tags: geometry, computer-puzzle, tiling, polyomino

**Inspired by** [Polyomino T hexomino and rectangle packing into rectangle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/polyomino-t-hexomino-and-rectangle-packing-into-rectangle])

**See also** series [Tiling rectangles with F pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64146/tiling-rectangles-with-f-pentomino-plus-rectangles) and [Tiling rectangles with Hexomino plus rectangle #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66754/tiling-rectangles-with-hexomino-plus-rectangle-1#66756)

**Next** puzzle in the series: [Tiling rectangles with Hexomino plus rectangle #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67014/tiling-rectangles-with-hexomino-plus-rectangle-2)

**The goal** is to tile rectangles as small as possible with the given hexomino, in this case number 1 of the 25 hexominoes which cannot tile a rectangle alone. We allow the addition of copies of a rectangle. For each rectangle $a\times b$, find the smallest area larger rectangle that copies of $a\times b$ plus at least one of the given hexomino will tile.

**Example** with the $1\times 1$ (or the $1\times 2$) you can tile a $2\times 5$ as follows:

[image: 5_2]

Now we don't need to consider $1\times 1$ (or $1\times 2$) further as we have found the smallest rectangle tilable with copies of the hexomino plus copies of $1\times 1$ (or $1\times 2$).

Currently known rectangles exist for the hexomino plus $1\times 3$, $1\times 4$, $1\times 5$, $1\times 6$, $1\times 7$, $1\times 8$, $1\times 9$, $1\times 10$, $1\times 11$, $1\times 12$, $1\times 13$, $1\times 14$, $1\times 15$, $1\times 16$, $1\times 18$, $1\times 19$, $1\times 20$, $1\times 26$, $2\times 2$, $2\times 3$, $2\times 5$, $2\times 7$, $3\times 4$, $3\times 5$

Most of them could be tiled by hand fairly easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the first one, for $2 \times 2$ is easy:

> 4x5=20
>  [image]

---

It turns out to be rather unique; **almost all** other solutions I've found so far are
part of three families of generalizable solutions, all of which are characterized by the
fact that

> the hexominos are lying next to each other, filling a narrow band of only two rows.

A summary of solution sizes is shown at the bottom.

---

#### Type A

Let's start with type A, which is the minimal solution for $1 \times 3$ and
$1 \times 4$ (shown):

> [image]

This works by

> putting $2k$ alternating hexominos in the indicated pattern, giving a bottom length
>  of $6k$ which can be covered with $n-1$ rows of horizontal $1 \times n$ rectangles when
>  $n$ divides $6k$. We'll need one horizontal rectangle on the top right, and $n$
>  vertical rectangles, giving a total box of $(n+1) \times (6k+n)$.
>
>  The minimum value of $k$ for which $n$ divides $6k$ is $\frac{\text{lcm}(6,n)}{6}$,
>  so the total box is $(n+1) \times (\text{lcm}(6,n)+n)$.

A generalizable solution for $2 \times n$, $n$ odd uses the same hexomino pattern. It's
the minimal solution for $2 \times 3$:

> [image]
>
>  The total box here is $2n \times (6k+2)$. The minimum value of $k$ for which $n$
>  divides $6k$ is $\frac{\text{lcm}(6,n)}{6}$, so the total box is
>  $2n \times (\text{lcm}(6,n)+2)$.

#### Type B

The minimal solution for $2 \times 7$ (and, by subdividing, $1 \times 7$) is

> [image]

This leads to a generalizable solution (for both $1 \times n$ and $2 \times \text{odd} n$)
by

> putting $2k+1$ alternating hexominos in the indicated pattern, giving a bottom length
>  of $6k+1$ which can be covered with $n-1$ rows of horizontal $1 \times n$ rectangles
>  when $n$ divides $6k+1$. The total box size is $(n+1) \times (6k+5)$.

#### Type C

The last type, C, uses the same hexomino pattern as B but 'flipped'. Here is the minimal
solution for $1 \times 11$:

> [image]

This leads to a generalizable solution (only for $1 \times n$) by

> putting $2k+1$ alternating hexominos in the indicated pattern, giving a bottom length
>  of $6k+5$ which can be covered with $n-1$ rows of horizontal $1 \times n$ rectangles
>  when $n$ divides $6k+5$. The total box size is $(n+1) \times (6k+1)+2n$.

---

Let's make a list of minimal solutions. For $1 \times n$:

> `axb  Type k Size           axb   Type k Size`
>  `1x3  A    1  4x 9 =  36    2x3   A    1  6x 8 =  48`
>  `1x4  A    2  5x16 =  80    2x4   -`
>  `1x5  C    0  6x11 =  66    2x5   B    4  6x29 = 174`
>  `1x6  A    1  7x12 =  84    2x6   -`
>  `1x7  B    1  8x11 =  88    2x7   B    1  8x11 =  88`
>  `1x8  A    4  9x32 = 288    2x8   -`
>  `1x9  A    3 10x27 = 270    2x9   A    3 18x20 = 360`
>  `1x10 A    5 11x40 = 440    2x10  -`
>  `1x11 C    1 12x29 = 348    2x11  B    9 12x59 = 708`
>  `1x12 A    2 13x24 = 312    2x12  -`
>  `1x13 B    2 14x17 = 238    2x13  B    2 14x17 = 238`
>  `1x14` (not minimal, see below)
>  `1x15 A    5 16x45 = 720    2x15  A    5 30x32 = 960`
>  `1x16 A    8 17x64 = 1088`
>  `1x17 C    2 18x47 = 846`
>  `1x18 A    3 19x36 = 684`
>  `1x19 B    3 20x23 = 460`

---

The minimal $1 \times 14$ is an exception and does not belong to the generalizable solutions mentioned above:

> 16x50=800
>  [image]

The solutions for $3 \times 4$ and $3 \times 5$ use the same hexomino pattern but take
more 'padding' to form a rectangle:

> 13x24 = 312
>  [image]
>  16x45 = 720
>  [image]

Finally, the $4 \times 5$ solution breaks with the pattern of generalizable solutions:

> 32x45 = 1440
>  [image]

Comment: Obviously the $2\times3$ solution gives you a $1\times3$ solution too, though maybe not optimal.

Comment: yeah, that's stated inside the spoiler. I'm not convinced it's minimal, I'll have to rewrite my tiling program to check.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't see that. Good work on the generalizable solution.

Comment: You can generalize $2 \times 2k+1$ by copying the $1 \times 2k+1$ generalization 4 times.

Comment: @phenomist I just posted an update with another (better?) generalizable solution for $2 \times n$, $n$ odd.

Comment: Your 2x2 is optimal, as is the 2x3. I'm not sure what your generalisation for the 1x3 would look like, I suspect it's not optimal. 1x4 is optimal, 2x5 is not.

Comment: I've added the 1x3 solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0U7A.png

Comment: Yup the 1x3 is optimal. Your 2x7 leads directly to a 1x7, both of those are optimal. A very similar arrangement gives the optimal 2x5 but it's quite a bit bigger.

Comment: ...you've been busy...  the 1x14 is not quite minimal, it's an exception to the expansions rules. I'm missing some minimal type A expansions, having to re-run width 1 to see what went wrong.

Comment: You're right, the $1 \times 14$ is completely different and rather beautiful. Who would've thought that ...

Comment: As posted it has a weird 'almost symmetry'. I found the same one. It offended my symmetry preference so I ran it again finding all solutions (three). The other two are nice and symmetric. You can just flip the section at the top or bottom containing just the hexominoes which are entirely in the top (or bottom) three rows to get the other two tilings.

Comment: Time to award this one I think...

Comment: I see you've removed the "might not be minimal" from 1x16, my program agrees 17x64 is minimal.