# Tiling rectangles with Heptomino plus rectangle #4

Tags: geometry, computer-puzzle, tiling, polyomino

**Inspired by** [Polyomino T hexomino and rectangle packing into rectangle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/polyomino-t-hexomino-and-rectangle-packing-into-rectangle)

**See also** series [Tiling rectangles with F pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64146/tiling-rectangles-with-f-pentomino-plus-rectangles) and [Tiling rectangles with Hexomino plus rectangle #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66754/tiling-rectangles-with-hexomino-plus-rectangle-1)

**Previous** puzzle in this series
[Tiling rectangles with Heptomino plus rectangle #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66976/tiling-rectangles-with-heptomino-plus-rectangle-3?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**Next** puzzle in this series [Tiling rectangles with Heptomino plus rectangle #6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67332/tiling-rectangles-with-heptomino-plus-rectangle-6/67373#67373)

**The goal** is to tile rectangles as small as possible with the given heptomino, in this case number 4 of the 108 heptominoes. We allow the addition of copies of a rectangle. For each rectangle $a\times b$, find the smallest area larger rectangle that copies of $a\times b$ plus at least one of the given heptomino will tile.

**Example** with the $1\times 1$ you can tile a $2\times 6$ as follows:

[image: 1x1_2x6]

Now we don't need to consider $1\times 1$ further as we have found the smallest rectangle tilable with copies of the heptomino plus copies of $1\times 1$.

I found 31 more but lots of them can be found by 'expansion rules' or pattern variations. I considered component rectangles of width 1 through 11 and length to 32 but my search was far from complete.

List of known sizes:

- Width 1: Lengths 1 to 15, 18, 22
- Width 2: Lengths 2 to 9, 11, 15, 21
- Width 3: Lengths 4, 5, 7
- Width 4: Length 5

Most of these could be tiled by hand using logic rather than trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general solution for $2\times n$ rectangles, with $n$ odd and not divisible by $7$.

> $2\times1$, in $2\times12$
>  [image]
>
>  $2\times3$, in $4\times40$
>  [image]
>
>  $2\times5$, in $6\times40$
>  [image]
>
>  and so on.
>
>  The size is $n+1$ by $2nk+10$, where $k\equiv n^{-1} \mod 7$.

Of course this general solution is not always optimal. Here are some better solutions:

$2\times1$

> in $2\times9$
>  [image]

$2\times3$

> in $8\times10$
>  [image]

Here is a general solution for $2\times n$ rectangles with $n$ even.

> $2\times2$, in $4\times12$
>  [image]
>
>  $2\times4$, in $6\times26$
>  [image]
>
>  $2\times6$, in $8\times82$
>  [image]
>
>  $2\times8$, in $10\times26$
>  [image]
>
>  $2\times10$, in $12\times110$
>  [image]
>  and so on.
>
>  The size is $n+2$ by $2nk+10$, where $k\equiv (\frac{n}{2})^{-1} \mod 7$.

Again this general solution is not always optimal:

$2\times6$

> in $8\times34$
>  [image]

Here is a general solution for $3\times n$ rectangles, where $n$ is not divisible by 3.

> $3\times4$, in $8\times31$
>  [image]
>
>  $3\times5$, in $20\times38$
>  [image]
>
>  $3\times7$, in $14\times10$
>  [image]
>  and so on.
>
>  The size is $2nr$ by $lcm(7,n)+3$, where $r\equiv n^{-1} \mod 3$.

There is in fact a general solution for any $a\times b$ where $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

> As $a$ and $b$ are co-prime, we can find positive $r$,$s$ such that $ra-sb=1$. This is equivalent to $(a-s)b-(b-r)a=1$. Doubling these equations, we can also find $t$,$u$ such that $ta-ub=2$ and $(a-u)b-(b-t)a=2$. The smallest $t$,$u$ are actually $t=(2r)\%b$ and $u=(2s)\%a$ where $\%$ is the modulo operator. This allows for the following solution:
>  [image]

Comment: 1x2=2x9, 2x2=4x12, 2x3=8x10, 2x4=6x26, 2x5=6x40, 2x6=8x34, 2x8=10x26 all minimal. 2x7 has a much smaller one than your generalisation, but 2x9=10x82, 2x11=12x54 and 2x15=16x40 are minimal (I think your formula gives those...). There is a nice smaller one for 2x21. Your 3x7=10x14 is minimal but 3x4 and 3x5 are not. Your axb generalisation seems to be minimal for 4x5=21x35.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a few generalizable $1 \times n$ solutions, similar to the ones [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66756/11110), corresponding to Type B, Type A resp. Type C:

> [image]

Note that they can be subdivided, e.g. the first one into $1 \times 4$ and $1 \times 2$ (though the latter won't be optimal; I'll leave it for another contender); in general,

> you'll need less rows as padding and the solution will have a height of $n + 1$.

Here are the solution sizes:

> **Type A** (middle): uses $2k$ heptominoes, works when $n$ divides $7k$. Solution size is $(n + 1) \times (7k + n)$, or equivalently $(n + 1) \times (\text{lcm}(7,n) + n)$.
>  **Type B** (left): uses $2k+1$ heptominoes, works when $n$ divides $7k + 1$. Solution size is $(n + 1) \times (7k + 6)$. The minimum value of $k$ is $7^{-1} \pmod n$ (this is a so-called [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)), so the solution size is $(n + 1) \times (7(7^{-1} \pmod n) + 6)$.
>  **Type C** (right): uses $2k+1$ heptominoes, works when $n$ divides $7k + 6$. Solution size is $(n + 1) \times (7k + 1 + 2n)$. The minimum value of $k$ is $7^{-1} \pmod n - 1$, so the solution size is $(n + 1) \times (7(7^{-1} \pmod n) - 6 + 2n)$.