# Tiling rectangles with Heptomino plus rectangle #6

Tags: geometry, computer-puzzle, tiling, polyomino

**Inspired by** [Polyomino T hexomino and rectangle packing into rectangle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/polyomino-t-hexomino-and-rectangle-packing-into-rectangle)

**See also** series [Tiling rectangles with F pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64146/tiling-rectangles-with-f-pentomino-plus-rectangles) and [Tiling rectangles with Hexomino plus rectangle #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66754/tiling-rectangles-with-hexomino-plus-rectangle-1)

**Previous** puzzle in this series
[Tiling rectangles with Heptomino plus rectangle #4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67149/tiling-rectangles-with-heptomino-plus-rectangle-4)

**Next** puzzle in this series
[Tiling rectangles with Heptomino plus rectangle #7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67472/tiling-rectangles-with-heptomino-plus-rectangle-7)

**The goal** is to tile rectangles as small as possible with the given heptomino, in this case number 6 of the 108 heptominoes. We allow the addition of copies of a rectangle. For each rectangle $a\times b$, find the smallest area larger rectangle that copies of $a\times b$ plus at least one of the given heptomino will tile.

**Example** with the $1\times 1$ you can tile a $2\times 5$ as follows:

[image: 1x1_2x5]

Now we don't need to consider $1\times 1$ further as we have found the smallest rectangle tilable with copies of the heptomino plus copies of $1\times 1$.

I found 14 more. I considered component rectangles of width 1 through 11 and length to 31 but my search was not complete.

List of known sizes:

- Width 1: Lengths 1 to 8, 10 to 12
- Width 2: Lengths 2, 3, 5
- Width 3: Length 5

Most of these could be tiled by hand using logic rather than just trial and error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, a more interesting heptomino :) (in the sense that previous ones all had generalizable solutions who looked very much like [this hexomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66756/11110))

Here's the minimal solution for $1 \times 2$:

> $3 \times 6 = 18$
>  [image]

and for $2 \times 2$:

> $6 \times 13 = 78$
>  [image]

For $3 \times 5$:

> $19 \times 22 = 418$
>  [image]

My program found another one for $2 \times 7$:

> $21 \times 30 = 630$
>  [image]

a very narrow one for $1 \times 10$:

> $6 \times 31 = 186$
>  [image]

another one for $1 \times 11$:

> $12 \times 32 = 384$
>  [image]

and another one for $1 \times 12$:

> $12 \times 26 = 312$
>  [image]

This is probably the $1 \times 8$ solution you're looking for:

> $17 \times 22 = 374$
>  [image]

I like how this one and Jaap's attempt are fundamentally different; this one is 'chaos' and the other one 'order'. It's asymmetric but it can be turned in a symmetric one; there are two ways to tile the irregular shape formed (twice) by the darker shaded polyominos. If you use the same one for both, you get a symmetric solution.

Here is the minimal solution for $1 \times 9$:

> $19 \times 22 = 418$
>  [image]

Comment: Yup 1x1=3x6, 2x2=6x13 both minimal. From 1x1 to 1x7 all would make nice hand tiling puzzles.

Comment: 3x5=19x22 is optimal yes.

Comment: got an extra dollar sign in the last one

Comment: I love the symmetry of all of these - including the asyymetric 2x7!

Comment: Your net area just shot up to 2400, time to award I think

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few more solutions.

$1\times3$

> $7\times7$
>  [image]

$1\times4$

> $7\times9$
>  [image]

$1\times5$

> $6\times9$
>  [image]

$1\times6$

> $6\times13$
>  [image]

$1\times7$

> $8\times14$
>  [image]

$2\times3$

> $13\times14$
>  [image]

$2\times5$

> $11\times14$
>  [image]

**Edit:**

Here is a $1\times8$ solution that is surely non-optimal.

> $26\times42$
>  [image]

Comment: Yup 1x3,4,5,6,7; 2x3,5 all optimal

Comment: @theonetruepath I added a 1x8 solution that is surely not optimal.

Comment: The 1x8 is a thing of beauty... but not optimal, as you say. My optimal solution is asymmetric, I haven't searched all solutions to see if there's a symmetric one.