# Tiling rectangles with Heptomino plus rectangle #7

Tags: geometry, no-computers, tiling, polyomino

**Inspired by** [Polyomino T hexomino and rectangle packing into rectangle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/polyomino-t-hexomino-and-rectangle-packing-into-rectangle)

**See also** series [Tiling rectangles with F pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64146/tiling-rectangles-with-f-pentomino-plus-rectangles) and [Tiling rectangles with Hexomino plus rectangle #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66754/tiling-rectangles-with-hexomino-plus-rectangle-1)

**Previous** puzzle in this series
[Tiling rectangles with Heptomino plus rectangle #6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67332/tiling-rectangles-with-heptomino-plus-rectangle-6)

**Next** puzzle in this series
[Tiling rectangles with a Heptomino plus 2x2 square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67562/tiling-rectangles-with-a-heptomino-plus-2x2-square)

**The goal** is to tile rectangles as small as possible with the given heptomino, in this case number 7 of the 108 heptominoes (see example below). We allow the addition of copies of a rectangle. For each rectangle $a\times b$, find the smallest area larger rectangle that copies of $a\times b$ plus at least one of the given heptomino will tile.

**Example** with the $1\times 1$ you can tile a $2\times 5$ as follows:

[image: 1x1_2x5]

Now we don't need to consider $1\times 1$ further as we have found the smallest rectangle tilable with copies of the heptomino plus copies of $1\times 1$.

I found only 7 more. I considered component rectangles of width 1 through 11 and length to 31 but my search may not be complete.

List of known sizes:

- Width 1: Lengths 1 to 5
- Width 2: Lengths 2, 3, 5

These could all be tiled by hand, of course the bigger ones will be challenging. I'm making this one a 'hand tiling only' puzzle. In other words, use a computer to do anything **except** look up or compute the arrangements.

Comment: There seem to be an awful lot of these. Are they just going to continue indefinitely? (Looking at the history, the earliest ones attracted rather more upvotes and favourite-ings than more recent ones have.) There are 108 different heptominoes and I'm not sure we really want 108 "tiling rectangle with heptomino plus rectangles" puzzles...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I think there are an awful lot of riddles. But this isn't my personal puzzle emporium so I let it slide. The real question is, are they that unpopular and/or without merit that they should simply not be here? I'm open to persuasion.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that they be deleted, or anything like that. I just don't look forward with particular joy to the next hundred puzzles that are exactly like this one but with a different choice of heptomino. And yes, there are too many bad riddles -- but they're all posted by different people, often newcomers to PSE, rather than one person posting a dozen riddles that all work the same way :-).

Comment: Well I have some sympathy for your feeling here: I don't look forward to the work involved in posting 100 more very similar puzzles. Maybe instead I will 'condense' them in some way to concentrate the more interesting ones in far fewer puzzles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for the $2\times5$. It obviously also works for $1\times5$.

> $16\times16$:
>  [image]

Here is a better $1\times5$ solution.

> $9\times16$:
>  [image]

Comment: 2x5=16x16 is minimal, there is a smaller 1x5. Just 1x4 and 1x5 left now... You are leading by area found, with just that one...

Comment: @theonetruepath I found a better solution for the $1\times5$.

Comment: Yep the 1x5=9x16 is minimal. Lucky last, the 1x4. Hint: Its tiling is smaller than that of the 1x5.

Comment: Your total area is 256+144=400. Glorfindel was 325 so you get the nod...

Answer (score 3):

$1 \times 2$:

> $3 \times 5 = 15$
>  [image]

$2 \times 2$:

> $4 \times 10 = 20$
>  [image]

$1 \times 3$:

> $7 \times 10 = 70$
>  [image]

and a variation on that theme which works for $2 \times 3$:

> $13 \times 10 = 130$
>  [image]

This is about as hard as I can solve without using even pen and paper to think them out (obviously I'm using Excel to make the pictures). <s>FWIW I'm working on an iPad app to help with tiling by hand, it's a good exercise to polish my Swift.</s> the app works now (more or less), and helped me finding a solution for $1 \times 4$:

> $9 \times 10 = 90$
>  [image]

Comment: Yup 1x2=3x5 and 2x2=4x10 are minimal.

Comment: 1x3=7x10, 2x3=10x13 both minimal

Comment: Yup 1x4=7x10 is minimal. All done!