# Tiling rectangles with a Heptomino plus 2x2 square

Tags: geometry, no-computers, tiling, polyomino

**Inspired by** [Polyomino T hexomino and rectangle packing into rectangle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/polyomino-t-hexomino-and-rectangle-packing-into-rectangle)

**See also** series [Tiling rectangles with F pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64146/tiling-rectangles-with-f-pentomino-plus-rectangles) and [Tiling rectangles with Hexomino plus rectangle #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66754/tiling-rectangles-with-hexomino-plus-rectangle-1)

**Previous** puzzle in this series
[Tiling rectangles with Heptomino plus rectangle #7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67472/tiling-rectangles-with-heptomino-plus-rectangle-7)

**The goal** is to tile rectangles as small as possible with each of the given heptominoes (see diagram in example below) plus 2x2 squares.

**Example** Using the snake heptomino 'e' plus 2x2 squares you can tile a $3\times 5$ as follows:
[image: 2_86_3x5]

Use each of these heptominoes. Solutions may exist for other heptominoes, I only found solutions for these ones. Note that I omitted labels 'W', 'j', 'l':
[image: Heptomino2x2KnownTilersLabelled2]

All of these could all be tiled by hand, of course the bigger ones will be challenging. I'm making this one a 'hand tiling only' puzzle. In other words, use a computer to do anything **except** look up or compute the arrangements.

Comment: There are trivial solutions for 'j' and 'l' - put two 'j's together to make a 2x7 rectangle.  If a 2x2 is required, stick it on the end to make a 2x9.  Likewise, two 'l's make a 2x7 and you can add a 2x2 on the end.  Or if the 2x2 is not required, one 'l' by itself makes a rectangle already.  'W' may be impossible.

Comment: j and I were omitted *because* they trivially make rectangles on their own. W is probably impossible, I haven't thought of an elegant way to  stop my program bogging down making width-7 right-angles when tiling the quarter plane.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting twist; indeed, the $2 \times 2$ are often hard to tile. Here are some of the solutions:

[image]

> [image]

[image]

> [image]

[image] [image]

> [image] [image]

[image]

> [image]

[image]

> [image]

[image]

> [image]

[image]

> [image]

[image]

> [image]

Here are two improvements on Jaap's tiles B and D:

> [image] [image]

and G (can't believe I've missed that one)

> [image]

Here's a better ($9 \times 10$) version of H:

> [image]

and the final three:

[image]

> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

Comment: You're over half way... all minimal I think, will check properly later.

Comment: OK all have labels now. Your first three are T,a=8x8 minimal, Q not. Then Y,U, neither is minimal. Z=3x6 b,n=3x5 all minimal. o no, m=4x12 yes. S=8x8 yes. P no. d=8x8 yes.f,c,V,P (again)=5x6 yes. k no, h=4x10 yes. X=8x10 yes. B=6x13 yes. D=12x16 yes. G=8x8 yes. H=9x10 yes. i nice but not minimal. R=10x12 yes. g=12x14 yes. Is that all, given you repeated 'P'?

Comment: I can't see any missing ones... just a few (7?) non-minimal.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

> All $14\times16$
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

[image]

> All $14\times14$
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

[image]

> All $8\times14$
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

[image]
Unlike the other solution sets, these three solutions are not related.

> $10\times12$
>  [image]
>  $8\times10$
>  [image]
>  $5\times10$
>  [image]

[image]

> All $16\times22$
>  [image]
>  [image]

Comment: Big effort. 14x16: A,C minimal, B,D not. 14x14: E,F minimal, G not. 8x14: H,I,J not minimal

Comment: @theonetruepath Glorfindel has found improvements for B,D,G, so I've been trying to find better solutions for H,I,J, but not getting very far. They all have $7\times16$ solutions, but that is the same area as the $8\times14$ I already found.

Comment: I found a better one for H (9x10 IIRC), will post it tomorrow.

Comment: I added labels which should agree with yours so far. Also I checked H,I,J. There is a smaller one for H but I and J are indeed the same as yours in area (7x16), apologies for that, hope you didn't waste too much time.