# Tiling rectangles with Hexomino plus rectangle #3

Tags: geometry, computer-puzzle, no-computers, tiling, polyomino

**Inspired by** [Polyomino T hexomino and rectangle packing into rectangle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/polyomino-t-hexomino-and-rectangle-packing-into-rectangle])

**See also** series [Tiling rectangles with F pentomino plus rectangles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64146/tiling-rectangles-with-f-pentomino-plus-rectangles) and [Tiling rectangles with Hexomino plus rectangle #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66754/tiling-rectangles-with-hexomino-plus-rectangle-1#66756)

**Previous** puzzle in this series:
[Tiling rectangles with Hexomino plus rectangle #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67014/tiling-rectangles-with-hexomino-plus-rectangle-2)

**The goal** is to tile rectangles as small as possible with the given hexomino, in this case number 3 of the 25 hexominoes which cannot tile a rectangle alone. We allow the addition of copies of a rectangle. For each rectangle $a\times b$, find the smallest area larger rectangle that copies of $a\times b$ plus at least one of the given hexomino will tile.

**Example** with the $1\times 1$, $1\times 2$, $1\times 3$ or $2\times 3$  you can tile a $3\times 4$ as follows:

[image: 1x1 1x2 1x3 2x3_3x4]

Now we don't need to consider $1\times 1$, $1\times 2$, $1\times 3$ or $2\times 3$ further as we have found the smallest rectangle tilable with copies of the hexomino plus copies of those rectangles.

This is split into two sections: Those tilable by hand, and those probably requiring a computer. Feel free to solve any of them by hand, but please don't post computer-found tilings for those in the no-computer section.

**No Computer section** All of these should be tiled by hand only. This also means please don't look up answers on the web... This does not preclude you from for example using an image program to manipulate shapes on the screen, just from using a computer to search for or automate the arrangement.

- Width 1: Lengths 1 to 3 (given), 4 to 8
- Width 2: Lengths 2, 3 (given), 4 to 9
- Width 3: Lengths 4 5 8
- Width 4: Lengths 4 (difficult but worth it) 5 6
- Width 5: Lengths 5 6

**Computer section** Master solvers may well solve these by hand.

- Width 1: Lengths 9 to 12
- Width 2: Lengths 10 12 14
- Width 3: Length 7
- Width 4: Length 7

Answer (score 4):

Here are attempts for 2x2:

> 4x4=16
>  [image]

For 3x4:

> 4x6=24
>  [image]

This one for 1x4 is slightly smaller:

> 4x5=20
>  [image]

for 2x6 (and 1x6):

> 3x8=24
>  [image]

and for 4x6

> 6x8=48
>  [image]

and for 2x4

> 4x8=32
>  [image]

Here's one for 2x7 (which works for 1x7 as well):

> 5x8=40
>  [image]

and here is its 'inverse', for 3x5 and 1x5:

> 7x6=42
>  [image]

I found a computer-generated one in my archives, for 1x9:

> 9x23=207
>  [image]

Comment: 2x2=4x4 is minimal, 3x4=4x6 is minimal, 1x4=4x6 is not, 1x6,2x6=3x8 both minimal, 4x6=6x8 is, 2x4=6x8 is not

Comment: Here are some updates. Solving these while driving to the office is hard ...

Comment: 1x4=4x5, 2x4=4x8 both minimal

Answer (score 2):

Minimal 5x5:

> 7 x 7 = 49
>  [image]

Minimal 1x8:

> 6 x 10 = 60
>  [image]

---

Added attempt at 2x5:

> 8 x 7 = 56
>  [image]

---

Non-minimal 1x5 attempt:

> 7 x 7 = 49
>  [image]

Comment: 5x5=7x7 is minimal, well spotted. 1x5 can be improved on. 1x8=6x10 also minimal.

Comment: @theonetruepath Thanks, I figured 1x5 wasn't minimal, but wasn't sure how to reduce it.  Added a 2x5 attempt.

Comment: 2x5=7x8 is minimal yes